# form doesn't send parameters to correct method

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following registration form in `Thymleaf, the problem is when i submit the button it just redirect me to login page.

Here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${newCustomer}" th:method="post" th:action="@{/dashboard/NewUserRegisteration}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" th:field="*{name}"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">address</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" th:field="*{address}"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" th:field="*{phone}"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" th:field="*{password}"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPass" th:field="*{confirmPass}"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>              


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button id="submit-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit query</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and here is the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method=POST, path="dashboard/NewUserRegisteration")  
    public String RegisterNewCustomer( @RequestParam(name = "name") UserDTO userDTO ){

         System.out.println("All Users are: ");

        return "redirect:"+ "/dashboard/login";
    }
```

As you can see, i expect to see the `"All Users are: "` printed when i push the button but it doesn't work.
and at the end here is the `UserDTO` class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class UserDTO {

    long id;
    String name;
    String address;
    String phone;
    String password;
    String userName;
    String confirmPass;
}
```

Comment: I suppose that `@RequestParam(name = "name")` is incorrect because your parameter name is `newCustomer` and it's not a request param, it's a `ModelAttribute`.

Comment: And the second - are you sure what you can see `System.out.println("All Users are: ");` ? Maybe you need to check logging parameters?

Comment: @sanluck how can i check  logging parameters?

Comment: First your controller method is wrong. Replace the `@RequestParam` with `@ModelAttribute` instead. The redirect to the login is that due to your controller or do you also use Spring Security or another security solution to protect things.

Answer (score 0):

Number one, did you consider that you specified this, that redirects to login page?:

```
return "redirect:"+ "/dashboard/login";
```

If that was not your intention, then in your code, you already specified the path to follow after execution of the controller method.

In the method you may be thinking of breaking it down like this

`

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path="dashboard/NewUserRegisteration") 
public String RegisterNewCustomer(Model model){
    UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
    model.addAttribute("newCustomer",user);
    userRepository.save(user);
    return "redirect:/dashboard/login";
}
```

`